# Share button and filter file extension in Gallery

Tags: android, mime-types

I want that my user, in a Gallery app, when they click on the "Share" button, can only see my app if the selected file is a mov file.

I check available mime type for mov files in : [Mime types](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-7.1.1_r43/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java)

I understand that I can do it in the AndroidManifest such as :

```
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/quicktime" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

But that's not working because all video files (mp4 for example) can be shared with my app too and that's not what I want.

Using this instead of mime type is not working either :

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*mov" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*MOV" />
```

How can I only see my app in share option only for .mov files ?

Comment: `can only see my app if the selected file is a mov file.` Why should it be possible that your app prevents the users to select my app? Pretty bad idea.

Comment: that's not the point